# loop over BigInteger values using foreach in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to loop over `BigInteger` values in `Kotlin` using the following code snippet. But it's telling `For-loop range must have an 'iterator()' method`. How can I loop over the `BigInteger` values in `Kotlin`?

```
private fun pow(base: BigInteger, power: BigInteger): String {
        for(i in BigInteger.ZERO..power){ //Giving error

        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you really need to have the `power` as a `BigInteger`? If you relax your constraints, you can use the built-in `pow` function on `BigInteger`: `base.pow(Int)`

Comment: No I can't. The function parameters are really huge. So that's the way to go. So you mean `Kotlin` doesn't provide us a way to iterate through `BigInteger` values using for loop? @Todd

Comment: While the answer provided by @caco3 is a nice way to write a BigInteger range, I think you really need to re-evaluate your assumptions here for this problem. Long.MAX_VALUE is 2^63-1, the largest number you can use without having to switch to `BigInteger`. Now, I understand that the *answer* to your calculation might exceed Long.MAX_VALUE, but calculating iteratively in a loop with an exponent that large will take many human lifetimes. Please, reconsider your assumptions and see if you can use the built-in function for this!

Comment: The fact that `BigInteger.pow` takes an `int` as an argument rather than `BigInteger` (it is even noted in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#pow-int-)) may confirm @Tedd 's words. Even though Kotlin is so *flexible* that it allows us to iterate over *anything* it may be not the best way to solve the problem you have

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can extend [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) to allow this

In particular we need to:

1. introduce `rangeTo` function to `BigInteger` (to allow using `..` `operator`)
2. add `iterator` function to the range returned by `rangeTo` `operator`

**The `rangeTo` function**

Here I'm defining an [extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extension-functions) for `BigInteger`

```
operator fun BigInteger.rangeTo(other: BigInteger) = 
        BigIntegerRange(this, other)
```

**`BigIntegerRange`**:

```
class BigIntegerRange(
        override val start: BigInteger,
        override val endInclusive: BigInteger
) : ClosedRange<BigInteger>, Iterable<BigInteger> {
    override operator fun iterator(): Iterator<BigInteger> =
            BigIntegerRangeIterator(this)
}
```

**`BigIntegerRangeIterator`**:

```
class BigIntegerRangeIterator(
        private val range: ClosedRange<BigInteger>
) : Iterator<BigInteger> {
    private var current = range.start

    override fun hasNext(): Boolean =
            current <= range.endInclusive

    override fun next(): BigInteger {
        if (!hasNext()) {
            throw NoSuchElementException()
        }
        return current++
    }
}
```

Now this code:

```
fun main() {
    for (i in BigInteger.ZERO..BigInteger.TEN) {
        println(i)
    }
}
```

Compiles and prints:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Do not forget to [`import`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/packages.html#imports) the `rangeTo` function

**See also**:

- [Ranges](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/ranges.html)
- [Control Flow. For Loops](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#for-loops)